# I am not able to filter through my array in React.js

Tags: reactjs, filter

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my filter in React.js. My React app is connected to a Node.js app which fetches my data from a Pokemon API. I basically just want to show one pokemon card on my front end route /pokemon:id and to do this I am filtering and then mapping through my array. For some reason this is not working and I was wondering if anyone can check my code and see if I'm making a simple mistake. I think the problem is in the way that I am filtering my pokemon card because when I take away the filter everything works. I have only been coding for 3 months so please forgive my sloppy code!

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      maxWidth: 345,
    },
    media: {
      height: 0,
      paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    },
    expand: {
      transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
      }),
    },
    expandOpen: {
      transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    },
  }));


const PokeDetail = ({ pokemon }) => {
     const { id } = useParams();

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  
    const handleExpandClick = () => {
      setExpanded(!expanded);
    };
   

return (
     <div>
          {pokemon.length >= 1 && 
             pokemon
                 .filter((poke) => {
                     return poke.id === id
          })
        .map((poke) => (
            <div>
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                   <CardHeader
                    title={poke.name.english}
                    subheader={poke.type}
                />
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image="/Images/"
                    title={poke.name.english}
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    Japanese: {poke.name.japanese} Chinese: {poke.name.chinese} French: {poke.name.french}
                    </Typography>
                    
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions disableSpacing>
                    <IconButton
                    className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                        [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                    })}
                    onClick={handleExpandClick}
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="show more"
                    >
                    <ExpandMoreIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </CardActions> 
                <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <CardContent>
                    <Typography paragraph>Description</Typography>
                    <Typography paragraph>

                                Attack: {poke.base.Attack} 
                                Defense: {poke.base.Defense} 
                                Speed: {poke.base.Speed}
                              
                    </Typography>
                    
                    </CardContent>
                </Collapse>
                </Card>
           </div>
          ))}
       
       </div>
     
        
     );
}; 

export default PokeDetail;
```

Comment: Are you sure that "pokemon" object is an array of objects (poke)? Can you add the add a console.log(JSON.stringify(pokemon, null, 2)) and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest you to separate the logic (JS code) from the view (HTML) in JSX, in order to have a cleaner code.

Since you want to display a single poke by id, I'd suggest you to use find instead of filter.

One more thing. **The "id" constant is a string.** You're using strict type checking (===) with a number, which will return false.

```
const foundPoke = pokemon.find(poke => poke.id === Number(id));

if (!foundPoke) {
  return <div>Not found!</div>
}

return (
  <div>
    {poke.name}
  </div>
);
```

I also assume that the "pokemon" prop doesn't return an array of objects. I added a comment on your questions asking you to paste an output of the console.log(JSON.stringify(pokemon, null, 2))

[A bit off topic] Since you said you're coding for 3 months only, I suggest you to use a proper IDE and configure eslint and prettier. These tools will help you with the code styling (I see indentation issues)

Comment: Thanks! I used the Number(id) approach with my original code and it worked! Thanks so much for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I get in the console:

```
[
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": {
      "english": "Nidoqueen",
      "japanese": "ニドクイン",
      "chinese": "尼多后",
      "french": "Nidoqueen"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison",
      "Ground"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 90,
      "Attack": 92,
      "Defense": 87,
      "Sp. Attack": 75,
      "Sp. Defense": 85,
      "Speed": 76
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "name": {
      "english": "Nidoran♂",
      "japanese": "ニドラン♂",
      "chinese": "尼多朗",
      "french": "Nidoran♂"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 46,
      "Attack": 57,
      "Defense": 40,
      "Sp. Attack": 40,
      "Sp. Defense": 40,
      "Speed": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "name": {
      "english": "Nidorino",
      "japanese": "ニドリーノ",
      "chinese": "尼多力诺",
      "french": "Nidorino"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 61,
      "Attack": 72,
      "Defense": 57,
      "Sp. Attack": 55,
      "Sp. Defense": 55,
      "Speed": 65
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": {
      "english": "Nidoking",
      "japanese": "ニドキング",
      "chinese": "尼多王",
      "french": "Nidoking"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison",
      "Ground"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 81,
      "Attack": 102,
      "Defense": 77,
      "Sp. Attack": 85,
      "Sp. Defense": 75,
      "Speed": 85
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "name": {
      "english": "Clefairy",
      "japanese": "ピッピ",
      "chinese": "皮皮",
      "french": "Mélofée"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fairy"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 70,
      "Attack": 45,
      "Defense": 48,
      "Sp. Attack": 60,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 35
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": {
      "english": "Clefable",
      "japanese": "ピクシー",
      "chinese": "皮可西",
      "french": "Mélodelfe"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fairy"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 95,
      "Attack": 70,
      "Defense": 73,
      "Sp. Attack": 95,
      "Sp. Defense": 90,
      "Speed": 60
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": {
      "english": "Vulpix",
      "japanese": "ロコン",
      "chinese": "六尾",
      "french": "Goupix"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fire"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 38,
      "Attack": 41,
      "Defense": 40,
      "Sp. Attack": 50,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 65
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": {
      "english": "Ninetales",
      "japanese": "キュウコン",
      "chinese": "九尾",
      "french": "Feunard"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fire"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 73,
      "Attack": 76,
      "Defense": 75,
      "Sp. Attack": 81,
      "Sp. Defense": 100,
      "Speed": 100
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "name": {
      "english": "Jigglypuff",
      "japanese": "プリン",
      "chinese": "胖丁",
      "french": "Rondoudou"
    },
    "type": [
      "Normal",
      "Fairy"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 115,
      "Attack": 45,
      "Defense": 20,
      "Sp. Attack": 45,
      "Sp. Defense": 25,
      "Speed": 20
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 40,
    "name": {
      "english": "Wigglytuff",
      "japanese": "プクリン",
      "chinese": "胖可丁",
      "french": "Grodoudou"
    },
    "type": [
      "Normal",
      "Fairy"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 140,
      "Attack": 70,
      "Defense": 45,
      "Sp. Attack": 85,
      "Sp. Defense": 50,
      "Speed": 45
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "name": {
      "english": "Zubat",
      "japanese": "ズバット",
      "chinese": "超音蝠",
      "french": "Nosferapti"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison",
      "Flying"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 40,
      "Attack": 45,
      "Defense": 35,
      "Sp. Attack": 30,
      "Sp. Defense": 40,
      "Speed": 55
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": {
      "english": "Golbat",
      "japanese": "ゴルバット",
      "chinese": "大嘴蝠",
      "french": "Nosferalto"
    },
    "type": [
      "Poison",
      "Flying"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 75,
      "Attack": 80,
      "Defense": 70,
      "Sp. Attack": 65,
      "Sp. Defense": 75,
      "Speed": 90
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 43,
    "name": {
      "english": "Oddish",
      "japanese": "ナゾノクサ",
      "chinese": "走路草",
      "french": "Mystherbe"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 45,
      "Attack": 50,
      "Defense": 55,
      "Sp. Attack": 75,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": {
      "english": "Gloom",
      "japanese": "クサイハナ",
      "chinese": "臭臭花",
      "french": "Ortide"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 65,
      "Defense": 70,
      "Sp. Attack": 85,
      "Sp. Defense": 75,
      "Speed": 40
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "name": {
      "english": "Vileplume",
      "japanese": "ラフレシア",
      "chinese": "霸王花",
      "french": "Rafflesia"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 75,
      "Attack": 80,
      "Defense": 85,
      "Sp. Attack": 110,
      "Sp. Defense": 90,
      "Speed": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "name": {
      "english": "Paras",
      "japanese": "パラス",
      "chinese": "派拉斯",
      "french": "Paras"
    },
    "type": [
      "Bug",
      "Grass"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 35,
      "Attack": 70,
      "Defense": 55,
      "Sp. Attack": 45,
      "Sp. Defense": 55,
      "Speed": 25
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "name": {
      "english": "Parasect",
      "japanese": "パラセクト",
      "chinese": "派拉斯特",
      "french": "Parasect"
    },
    "type": [
      "Bug",
      "Grass"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 95,
      "Defense": 80,
      "Sp. Attack": 60,
      "Sp. Defense": 80,
      "Speed": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "name": {
      "english": "Venonat",
      "japanese": "コンパン",
      "chinese": "毛球",
      "french": "Mimitoss"
    },
    "type": [
      "Bug",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 55,
      "Defense": 50,
      "Sp. Attack": 40,
      "Sp. Defense": 55,
      "Speed": 45
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "name": {
      "english": "Venomoth",
      "japanese": "モルフォン",
      "chinese": "摩鲁蛾",
      "french": "Aéromite"
    },
    "type": [
      "Bug",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 70,
      "Attack": 65,
      "Defense": 60,
      "Sp. Attack": 90,
      "Sp. Defense": 75,
      "Speed": 90
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 50,
    "name": {
      "english": "Diglett",
      "japanese": "ディグダ",
      "chinese": "地鼠",
      "french": "Taupiqueur"
    },
    "type": [
      "Ground"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 10,
      "Attack": 55,
      "Defense": 25,
      "Sp. Attack": 35,
      "Sp. Defense": 45,
      "Speed": 95
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 51,
    "name": {
      "english": "Dugtrio",
      "japanese": "ダグトリオ",
      "chinese": "三地鼠",
      "french": "Triopikeur"
    },
    "type": [
      "Ground"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 35,
      "Attack": 100,
      "Defense": 50,
      "Sp. Attack": 50,
      "Sp. Defense": 70,
      "Speed": 120
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 52,
    "name": {
      "english": "Meowth",
      "japanese": "ニャース",
      "chinese": "喵喵",
      "french": "Miaouss"
    },
    "type": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 40,
      "Attack": 45,
      "Defense": 35,
      "Sp. Attack": 40,
      "Sp. Defense": 40,
      "Speed": 90
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 53,
    "name": {
      "english": "Persian",
      "japanese": "ペルシアン",
      "chinese": "猫老大",
      "french": "Persian"
    },
    "type": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 65,
      "Attack": 70,
      "Defense": 60,
      "Sp. Attack": 65,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 115
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "name": {
      "english": "Psyduck",
      "japanese": "コダック",
      "chinese": "可达鸭",
      "french": "Psykokwak"
    },
    "type": [
      "Water"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 50,
      "Attack": 52,
      "Defense": 48,
      "Sp. Attack": 65,
      "Sp. Defense": 50,
      "Speed": 55
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 55,
    "name": {
      "english": "Golduck",
      "japanese": "ゴルダック",
      "chinese": "哥达鸭",
      "french": "Akwakwak"
    },
    "type": [
      "Water"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 80,
      "Attack": 82,
      "Defense": 78,
      "Sp. Attack": 95,
      "Sp. Defense": 80,
      "Speed": 85
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 56,
    "name": {
      "english": "Mankey",
      "japanese": "マンキー",
      "chinese": "猴怪",
      "french": "Férosinge"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fighting"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 40,
      "Attack": 80,
      "Defense": 35,
      "Sp. Attack": 35,
      "Sp. Defense": 45,
      "Speed": 70
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 57,
    "name": {
      "english": "Primeape",
      "japanese": "オコリザル",
      "chinese": "火暴猴",
      "french": "Colossinge"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fighting"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 65,
      "Attack": 105,
      "Defense": 60,
      "Sp. Attack": 60,
      "Sp. Defense": 70,
      "Speed": 95
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 58,
    "name": {
      "english": "Growlithe",
      "japanese": "ガーディ",
      "chinese": "卡蒂狗",
      "french": "Caninos"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fire"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 55,
      "Attack": 70,
      "Defense": 45,
      "Sp. Attack": 70,
      "Sp. Defense": 50,
      "Speed": 60
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 59,
    "name": {
      "english": "Arcanine",
      "japanese": "ウインディ",
      "chinese": "风速狗",
      "french": "Arcanin"
    },
    "type": [
      "Fire"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 90,
      "Attack": 110,
      "Defense": 80,
      "Sp. Attack": 100,
      "Sp. Defense": 80,
      "Speed": 95
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 60,
    "name": {
      "english": "Poliwag",
      "japanese": "ニョロモ",
      "chinese": "蚊香蝌蚪",
      "french": "Ptitard"
    },
    "type": [
      "Water"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 40,
      "Attack": 50,
      "Defense": 40,
      "Sp. Attack": 40,
      "Sp. Defense": 40,
      "Speed": 90
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the conditional statement.

```
pokemon.length >= 1 &&
```

Comment: This check doesn't make sense anyway, but removing it won't help neither. If length === 0, then pokemon.map() will return an empty array which won't render anything in the DOM

Answer (score -1):

please try ;

```
{pokemon.length >= 1 && 
  pokemon.map(poke=>{
    if(poke.id === id) {
      <div>
         ...
      </div>
   }
 })
```

Comment: This code will try to render undefined values for each item which is different than the on you're looking for, which will result with an error. First you need to remove all unnecessary data, then map through the list